# What kind of isolation does application domain provide to Assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net

What kind of isolation does application domain provide to Assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.beansoftware.com/NET-Tutorials/Application-Domain.aspx

Comment: +1 for the link. I like to think of them as lightweight processes. If .NET were an OS and it gets close in some ways, it would be its processes.